# How to redirect non-logged in users from a URL to a specific page?

Tags: wp-redirect

I've found an [existing solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/how-to-redirect-non-logged-in-users-to-a-specific-page) for redirecting posts and pages to a specific page:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( is_page('add page slug or i.d here') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/' ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

However, I'm trying to redirect **from** a url to a specific page. The page slug/page id method isn't working because the page I want to redirect is created by a plugin and it is not in the list of Pages or Posts in WordPress. Thus, it does not have a page slug or id that I can use.

I'm a novice at php, so hoping someone can share how the above function can be modified so that I can redirect from a url (as opposed to a page slug or id #). Is it simply a matter of changing "is_page" to something else that checks the url?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can hard-code it and check the URL for that page, but it is always better to check with that plugin author, they might have something to make it easier, e.g a function, query variable, etc..

Comment: @SamuelElh unfortunately I had previously contacted the plugin author, and no such function exists...hence why I'm looking to modify the snippet above :)

Comment: If you know the URL then can't you check against $_SERVER?

Comment: Try then [`se_238650_nonwp_page_check($slug)`](http://pastebin.com/MN8wcUhX) in the place of `is_page`..