# How to restrict an entire WordPress site to visitors, but the register and login page?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-recommendation

## Restrict Website, But Login and Register Page

---

#### I want my my entire WordPress site to be restricted to visitors, but I want the register and login page to be accessible (not restricted) to the visitors

Since my website is a members-only website, I want to restrict it's access so that visitors only see 2 pages, the login page and the register page.

I have tried multiple plugins to do exactly that but unfortunately for me, I haven't been able to find the right one. Some plugins redirect the entire website to one page while other plugins require custom redirection settings for each page to be separately added.

***What I want:-***

1. **Restrict entire WordPress website to visitors by redirection.**
2. **Do not restrict 2 pages, Login Page and Registration Page.**
3. **Redirect Users to Login Page and/or Register Page.**

There is an  option in my Login Page to view the Register Page.
I want both of these pages to be accessible to the visitor and the rest of the website to be inaccessible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/how-to-redirect-non-logged-in-users-to-a-specific-page

Answer (score 3):

Below code will work with WordPress default login/register screens:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'member_only_site' );
function member_only_site( ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in( ) ) {
          auth_redirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What file should I add this in? Also, I also want to redirect users to my register page.. How can I do that?

Comment: I added it in the functions.php. I just wanna know how to redirect to the register page too.

Comment: By default it takes user to WordPress default login page. If you enable "Anyone can register" option from **Settings > General** then you will see a register link on login screen. From user experience perspective I think taking user to login & then showing there registration link is just perfect. Because those who have already registered can directly login & those who have not registered, can register on the site by clicking on **Register** link.

Comment: I did enable Anyone can register but when I click on register from the login page it redirects to the login page again.

Comment: Can you share website link by any chance?

Comment: It's offline, I have installed WP locally. I think I have to use is_page but I dont know how.

Comment: ` if ( ! is_user_logged_in( ) && is_page('register' == false) ) {
  auth_redirect();
  }
    }`

Comment: `if ( ! is_user_logged_in( ) && ! is_page( 'register' ) ) {
    auth_redirect();
 }`

Comment: not working, giving error, 'Local host redirected too many times'

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative:

```
global $pagenow;

$accessible_pages = array('wp-login.php', 'wp-login.php?action=register');

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !in_array($pagenow, $accessible_pages) && !is_admin() ) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

You can insert in the array "accessible_pages" the pages (separated by commas) that you want to be public-accessible to visitors, avoiding redirects to the login page every time that a page is loaded.

Comment: not working, redirecting to login page when I go to the register url.

Comment: It wasn't working because you needed to change the "register" page to match yours. Changed the array for you, assuming that you're using the **default** wordpress registration page; try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function redi() {
global $pagenow;
if (!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php' && $pagenow !='wp-login.php?action=register') {
wp_redirect('wp-login.php?action=register');
}}  add_action('template_redirect', 'redi');
```