# Force users to register in order to view website

Tags: login, user-registration, facebook

I would like to avoid anonymous visiting to my wordpress site.
It is focused to a very small community from our neighborhood. I would like to force users to register themselves by facebook or regular login.

Is that possible somehow?

I tried to find a plugin for it, but I was not able to found anything.

Comment: I bet there's a plugin somewhere for binding to facebook credentialing services.  Your general question already has a solution, here:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/how-to-redirect-non-logged-in-users-to-a-specific-page

Comment: Check out the Force Login plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/

Answer (score 2):

I use the WP-Members plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/ ). It allows you to block/not block by default, and block/unblock individual pages. Works well for me.

There are similar plugins available.