# prevent anonymous access to Wordpress site (non-admin site)

Tags: plugins, security, authentication

I'm using WP to build a help/training portal for a commercial software product (Product X).  We'd like to restrict access to this new WP site to only authenticated users of Product X as it contains sensitive information. Integrating with Product X's auth API is not a problem (I've done this before). However, all the docs/examples related to customizing WP auth seem focused on the WP admin portal, not the actual WP site.  Is such a thing supported? If so, links to examples/docs would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible to redirect all non-logged in users to the login page.  Then you restrict who can/can not register for the site, so I assume you'd use Product X's API to authenticate/create accounts. I guess you'd have to build some sort of single sign-on utility, so they'd sign in to Product X's site and then be auto-logged in via WordPress?

Comment: This is a basic method:
https://www.peterstavrou.com/blog/website/redirect-user-not-logged-wordpress/

Also take a look at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect

See Yahya's answer to this question:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/how-to-redirect-non-logged-in-users-to-a-specific-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect non-logged in users to a specific page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/how-to-redirect-non-logged-in-users-to-a-specific-page)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your header.php file, or a file that will be loaded at the top of every page.

```php
<?php
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect('/wp-login.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Someone will probably point out a reason why not to do this, but it's the first thing that came to mind.