# Redirect user to a form until they have filled it out

Tags: redirect, membership, signup

I would like new users to be redirected to a page with a form until they have filled out the form and submitted it, so that their profile information is complete.

I guess this would be considered a membership site although I am not sure yet if I will use any dedicated plugins. I am only using woocommerce so far. What would be the right approach for this? If there are already plugins that do such a thing I did not find them. Thanks!

Comment: I've not used woocommerce yet, but I have used UltimateMember. There is likely a way to conditionally restrict pages to the login/registration page within the configuration. Or perhaps you will need to start hacking your theme a bit. For instance: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/how-to-redirect-non-logged-in-users-to-a-specific-page