# How to redirect non logged in mobile users to page on same site?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, mobile

I have seen many like this question (like [How to redirect non-logged in users to a specific page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/how-to-redirect-non-logged-in-users-to-a-specific-page)) but none have worked.

this is basically what I've come up with but it doesn't work all the time and has a refresh loop afterwards.

```
if ((screen.width <= 800) && (document.location="https://example.com/")) {
    window.location.replace = "https:example.com/m-home-page/";
    window.location.reload();
}
```

This is a php I was testing as well which redirected the blog page to the home page for some reason. (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438523/how-to-redirect-logged-out-users-to-different-page-in-wordpress)

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
wp_redirect( home_url('/m-home-pages') ); // This will redirect to the home page which we have created.
exit;
}
else
{
wp_redirect( home_url() );// this will redirect to the site main home page.
exit; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the js you provided you can just do this

```js
if ((screen.width <= 800) && (document.location="https://example.com/")) {
    location.href = "https:example.com/m-home-page/";
}
```

You could also do this more dynamically using async request but if this solution is enough for you atm then go with it first.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer unfortunately it didn't work properly I have a feeling there might be something broken on my end.

when activated it creates an infinite refresh loop which I can manually stop but it just has a blank screen.

I am using buddyboss child theme and injected the code into the custom .js file if that helps.

Comment: Update it does the refresh loop in every page on mobile